# Timing out with alarm when waiting on input on Perl in Windows

Tags: windows, perl, timeout

Is there an alternative for alarm function in Perl to be used on Windows?

Alarm doesn't seem to work in Windows.

The below code should timeout if no user input is given within N seconds. The code works good in linux but hangs in there on Windows.

CODE:

```
$SIG{ALRM} = \&input_timed_out;

eval {

        alarm(10);

        $input = <>;
        alarm(0);   
        print $input."\n";
}

print "eval exit with:  $@  \n";

if ( $@ =~ /NO USER INPUT IN TIME/ ) {

       print "Timed out.\n";
       $input = "quit";
}

print "Answer is $input\n";

sub input_timed_out {

           die "NO USER INPUT IN TIME";

}
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? `alarm` works for Windows, for example like: `perl -wle "alarm(3); sleep 10"`. Please [edit] your post and show an [mcve] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Corion-> Added my code that causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy/convenient way to get a timeout on `STDIN` on Windows Perl. The following implements a simple-minded readline function with a timeout. It doesn't handle backspace or cursor keys, so you will still have to implement these. It demonstrates how to implement a timeout on Windows for STDIN.

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadKey;

sub timed_input {
   my $end_time = time + shift;
   my $string ;
   do {
       my $key = ReadKey(1);
       $string .= $key if defined $key;
       print "\r$string" if (defined $string);
   } while (time < $end_time);
   return $string
};

my $input = '';
if( -t ) { 
    # we are interactive 
    $input = timed_input(3);
} else {
    $input = <>;
};
print "Input is [$input]\n";
```